# Importerror : cannot import name

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have been working on a node using a normal python IDE (spyder). Everything works fine, I can import all the needed python modules, some installed in /usr/local/lib and other in /usr/lib .
When I run my code with rosrun,

```
    from withings import WithingsAuth, WithingsApi
ImportError: cannot import name WithingsAuth
```

withings is a module that was installed under
Does somebody know how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167511/importerror-:-cannot-import-name/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently, when a ROS package has the same name as a python module, there is a conflict. Changing my packages's name to withings_pkg solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-05-20**:
I put my python script in the src folder. While generating srv headers, the python srv are automatically put on the withings/src/withings folder so if I try doing  "from withing import" it will look on the local folder instead of the global libraries folder of python.